# Terraspace: Call terraform with -target option

Tags: terraform, terraspace

We use terraspace to manage our infrastructure. Because of dependend resources, we need to call terraform apply twice, once with an option target, once without.

What we are currently doing:

`terraspace up somestack`

Then we get an error:

```
The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.
```

Then we change to *.terraspace-cache/location/env/stacks/somestack* and call

```
terraform apply -target module.someservice
```

After that

```
terraform apply
```

The question is: can this be automated, that we are done with just `terraspace up somestack` and would this be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `terraspace` version **2.1.6** you can now include `-target` flag with either:

- `terraspace plan`; or
- `terraspace up`

As according to this merged PR:
https://github.com/boltops-tools/terraspace/pull/258

> before the PR: the "target" argument was not passed down to terraform
>
> after the PR: it is passed (speeds things up)

Example given:

> You can test with `terraspace up -target=a.given.resource`